# How can I delete files from folders and subfolders before deleting the subfolders themselves in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Deleting a directory in Win32 API (RemoveDirectory) requires all files under that folder to be deleted before deleting the folder. So assuming I have a folder 'foo' at the root, with files in it, along with some subfolders that also may or may not have files, how do I recursively delete all the files, and then the subfolders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It generally requires a recursive function, that reads the contents of the directory you want to delete (via `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()`) - if a file is encountered, delete it, otherwise recurse into the folder and then delete the folder when the recursion returns.

Or you can just use [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the system will do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, could you please share a code sample with the IFileOperation interface? The MSDN page doesn't have one.

Comment: A full sample that demonstrates the extension of IFileOperation is included in the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK). In a default installation, it can be found at %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\WinUI\Shell\AppPlatform\FileOperations.

Comment: Note that you can also use `SHFileOperation()` which is simpler to use, although not as flexible (and it's more or less deprecated these days).