# How can I add text to the file I create using IFileOperation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I looked at the MSDN samples for IFileOperation, and they show how to create a file, but I don't want to create a blank file, I want to add some text in it. Here's what I have from the sample:

```
IFileOperation *pfo;
HRESULT hr = CreateAndInitializeFileOperation(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfo));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pfo->NewItem(psiFolder, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, c_szFileName, NULL, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfo->PerformOperations();
    }
    pfo->Release();
}
```

In the pfo->NewItem call, the fourth parameter is for the template, but I don't want to define a template.I want to create a .Url file with the content:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=www.google.com
```

I can't even seem to control the format of the file, let alone the content. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFileOperation::NewItem` lets you access the functionality of the 'ShellNew' menu (the menu you get if you right-click in a folder, and select *New* from the context menu). It's designed to let you make a folder or an empty file, or create a new file from a pre-existing template. It doesn't let you make a file containing arbitrary data.

Once you've created a new empty file you could open it using `CreateFile()` and write your data to it using `WriteFile()`. But note that `CreateFile()` could create the file for you as well - there's really no need to use `IFileOperation` simply to create an empty file (unless you need its support for UAC to create the file in a protected location, but in that case you'll have trouble writing to it afterwards).

Comment: I'm trying to write to the Favorites folder C:\Users\username\Favorites. Is that considered a protected location? I have used CreateFile to create a file successfully elsewhere; the reason I switched to IFileOperation was because it's easier to delete files and I wanted to keep the creation and deletion logic consistent

Comment: Is `IFileOperation` really easier to use than `DeleteFile()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I assume the OP is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303175/how-can-i-delete-files-from-folders-and-subfolders-before-deleting-the-subfolder

Comment: @Freakishly: No, the Favorites folder isn't normally protected so `CreateFile()` would be fine for that. You should mix and match technologies based on what works best - there's no reason to use `IFileOperation` for **everything** just because it makes one particular operation easier.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, Jonathan, and yes that's the original question I posted a few days ago.